# Terraform - replace bunch of blocks with for_each

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run, hashicorp-vault

Problem looks like very trivial but unfortunatelly I was not able to find solution. So, I'm reading kv2 secret from vault and creating google cloudrun service by google_cloud_run_service resource. I want to dynamically inject entire secret fetched from vault into cloudrun service as environmental variables. At this moment code looks like that (realtive parts of code only):

```
data "vault_kv_secret_v2" "cloudrun_platform_api_env" {
  mount = "kv"
  name  = "path/to/platform-api"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "platform_api" {
  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        env {
          name  = "VAR1"
          value = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data["VAR1"]
        }
        env {
          name  = "VAR2"
          value = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data["VAR2"]
        }
        env {
          name  = "VAR3"
          value = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data["VAR3"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above code works.

I'd like to get dif of separate declaration of `env` block for each variable and just load everything "blindly" from vault into cloudrun env.

Tried different approaches but nothing works.

Any suggestions ?

---

I will update that post when new suggestions are coming.

First one:
Use Terraform dynamic block + for_each:

```
dynamic "env" {
  for_each = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.platform_api_env
  content {
    name  = env.key
    value = env.value
   }
}
```

Failed:

```
adam@Adams-MacBook-Air latest % terraform plan
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
<truncated>

Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value
│ 
│   on cloudrun-platform-api.tf line 30, in resource "google_cloud_run_service" "platform_api":
│   30:           for_each = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.platform_api_env.data
│ 
│ Cannot use a map of string value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.
╵



adam@Adams-MacBook-Air latest % git diff cloudrun-platform-api.tf 
diff --git a/terraform/latest/cloudrun-platform-api.tf b/terraform/latest/cloudrun-platform-api.tf
index 115c7ad..aa98095 100644
--- a/terraform/latest/cloudrun-platform-api.tf
+++ b/terraform/latest/cloudrun-platform-api.tf
@@ -3,6 +3,12 @@ resource "google_cloud_run_service" "platform_api" {
   location                   = var.region
   autogenerate_revision_name = true
 
+  lifecycle {
+    ignore_changes = [
+      metadata[0].annotations["run.googleapis.com/operation-id"],
+    ]
+  }
+
   metadata {
     annotations = {
       "run.googleapis.com/client-name"    = "terraform"
@@ -20,101 +26,12 @@ resource "google_cloud_run_service" "platform_api" {
         ports {
           container_port = 80
         }
-        env {
-          name  = "VAR1"
-          value = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data["VAR1"]
-        }
-        env {
-          name  = "VAR2"
-          value = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data["VAR2"]
-        }
-        env {
-          name  = "VAR3"
-          value = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data["VAR3"]
-        }
+        dynamic "env" {
+          for_each = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.platform_api_env.data
+          content {
+            name  = env.key
+            value = env.value
+          }
         }
 
         startup_probe {
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried with the errors as well?

Comment: Have you tried iterating each map entry in `data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data` in the  containers block `for_each = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data`?

Comment: sure, tried that. check comment in suggested answer below

Comment: @webcitron it's hard to me to tell what kind of data is returned. Can you add to the question what is the output of `data.vault_kv_secret_v2.platform_api_env.data`, removing any sensitive data of course?

Comment: Sure @MarkoE, but can you enlighten me how I can output type of that data entry ?

Comment: Ok, foudn that. its map of strings. part of defined output variable for debug:
"planned_values": {
    "outputs": {
      "o": {
        "sensitive": true,
        "type": [
          "map",
          "string"
        ],
        "value": {
          "API_KEY_ROOT": "xxx",
          "API_KEY_WP": "xxx",
          "APP_DEBUG": "xxx",...

Comment: Ah, output.o is simply 
output "o" {
  value     = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data
  sensitive = true
}

Comment: Ok, so there are keys other than `VAR1`, `VAR2`, and `VAR3` or those are the ones you want?

Comment: that map is long. I've pasted just few examples. its basically entire secret (kv2) from vault

Comment: and of course im using differnet keys names (VAR1, VAR2, are just examples, in reality keys names are not contains incremental integer of course)

Comment: The suggestion to use a dynamic block with `for_each = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data` is correct. `*vault.KVSecret.Data` is a `map[string]interface{}` which when coerced in Terraform with `tftype` would be enumerable in the dynamic block. The issue with the attempt in the question is there is a typo where the `data` is not being accessed within `data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env`. Fix that typo and your results should be vastly improved.

Comment: Is your `data.vault_kv_secret_v2.platform_api_env.data` value considered by Terraform to be "sensitive"? If so, I think you might have encountered this known bug: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/29744

Comment: Indeed, got that but mentioned by @MartinAtkins. Thanks so much for help !

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `env` as `dynamic` and then iterate over the fields returned by the vault resource.

Something similar to:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "platform_api" {
  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        dynamic "env" {
          for_each = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data
          content {
            name  = env.key
            value = env.value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is one of ways I've tried. This is also solution suggested by chatgpt :) after these chagnes im getting following output: 


```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value
│ 
│   on cloudrun-platform-api.tf line 30, in resource "google_cloud_run_service" "platform_api":
│   30:           for_each = data.vault_kv_secret_v2.platform_api_env.data
│ 
│ Cannot use a map of string value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.
```

Comment: @webcitron How about iterating the keys for the map  `for_each = keys(data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data)`

Comment: What if the `for_each` is changed to look like this: `for_each = {for key, value in data.vault_kv_secret_v2.cloudrun_platform_api_env.data : key => value }`

Comment: thats also failed with:

`│ Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value
│ 
│   on cloudrun-platform-api.tf line 30, in resource "google_cloud_run_service" "platform_api":
│   30:           for_each = {for key, value in data.vault_kv_secret_v2.platform_api_env.data : key => value }
│ 
│ Cannot use a object value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.`